# Add document access denied

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, angularjs-http, azure-cognitive-search

We've created an AngularJS 1 project and we can successfully use the search functionality using a POST. We added a controller for adding documents to an index but we keep getting the message

> XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied

And the same index we search.

We've insured that CORS is enabled for the index.

Here is our code:

```
var value = [
  {
    "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
    "id": vm.id,
    "name": vm.name,
    "keywords": vm.keywords,
    "url": vm.url
  }
];

var url = "https://xxx.search.windows.net/indexes/xxx/docs/index?api-version=2015-02-28";

ModalService.showLoading();

$http({
  method: "POST",
  url: url,
  headers: {
    "api-key": "XXX",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  data: {
    "value": value
  }
})
.success(function (data, status) {
  vm.results = data;
  ModalService.hideLoading();
})
.error(function (data, status) {
  ModalService.hideLoading();
  ModalService.showError(data);
});
```

There is documentation that you can use REST to add new documents, so I'm not sure what we're missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Search only allows queries through CORS. This is documented on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn798941.aspx):

> CORS Options
>   Client-side JavaScript cannot call any APIs by default since the browser will prevent all cross-origin requests. To allow cross-origin queries to your index, enable CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) by setting the corsOptions attribute. Note that for security reasons, **only query APIs support CORS**.

The reason is that your client would need access to an admin API key to modify the index, and since you can't really trust the client, that seems like a bad idea.

We recommend that you do any operations that modify your index from a service that can authenticate the client first.